# XSLT Grouping and merging nodes

Tags: xslt, merge, grouping

Is it possible to group nodes and merge with a specified key? Some of my xml files have information about one person in two child nodes and I would like to find if nodes are about the same person and then marge it into one node

Input xml looks like this:

```
<db>
    <next>
        <name>John</name>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
        <number>304888</number>
        <details>
            <city>Westfield</city>
            <zip-code>07090</zip-code>
            <address>23 Victoria Street</address>
            <phone>123456789</phone>
            <fax/>
        </details>
    </next>
    <next>
        <name>John</name>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
        <number>304888</number>
        <details>
            <city>Westfield</city>
            <zip-code>07090</zip-code>
            <address>23 Victoria Street</address>
            <phone>223344123</phone>
            <fax>993456789</fax>
        </details>
    </next>
    <next>
        <name>John</name>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
        <number>113190</number>
        <details>
            <city>Richmond</city>
            <zip-code>3121</zip-code>
            <address>18 Seasame Street</address>
            <phone>123456222</phone>
            <fax/>
        </details>
    </next>
    <next>
        <name>John</name>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
        <number>113190</number>
        <details>
            <city>Richmond</city>
            <zip-code>3133</zip-code>
            <address>23 Baker Street</address>
            <phone>113344123</phone>
            <fax>133456789</fax>
        </details>
    </next>
</db>
```

'number' is an ID of the person and there can be more people with the same name and surename but with different 'number' value. Also, there can be the same person more than once (with the same value of 'name', 'surename' and 'number') but with different details. If the combination of 'city', 'zip-code' and 'address' are the same but 'phone' or/and 'fax' are differend then I would like to marge it.
And I want it to look like this:

```
<db>
    <next>
        <name>John</name>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
        <number>304888</number>
        <details>
            <city>Westfield</city>
            <zip-code>07090</zip-code>
            <address>23 Victoria Street</address>
            <phone>123456789</phone>
            <phone>223344123</phone>
            <fax>993456789</fax>
        </details>
    </next>
    <next>
        <name>John</name>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
        <number>113190</number>
        <details>
            <city>Richmond</city>
            <zip-code>3121</zip-code>
            <address>18 Seasame Street</address>
            <phone>123456222</phone>
            <fax/>
        </details>
    </next>
    <next>
        <name>John</name>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
        <number>113190</number>
        <details>
            <city>Richmond</city>
            <zip-code>3133</zip-code>
            <address>23 Baker Street</address>
            <phone>113344123</phone>
            <fax>133456789</fax>
        </details>
    </next>
</db>
```

I have tried muenchian grouping but I don't know how to do it with phone and fax nodes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="index" match="next" use="number" />
  <xsl:key name="details-key" match="details" use="city,'_',zip-code,'_',address" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="db">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="//next[generate-id() = generate-id(key('index', number)[1])]">
        <xsl:element name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="surname">
          <xsl:value-of select="surname"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="number">
          <xsl:value-of select="number"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <next>
          <xsl:for-each select="//details[generate-id() = generate-id(key('details-key', concat(city,'_',zip-code,'_',address))[1])]">
            <xsl:element name="city">
              <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="zip-code">
              <xsl:value-of select="zip-code"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="address">
              <xsl:value-of select="address"/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </next>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: If you have tried Muenchian grouping then you know that the answer to your question is yes, it is possible, but your implementation is wrong. Show us your code and we'll tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: I just edited my question showing my attempt

Comment: The example is ambiguous. Do you want to group the `next `elements by the value  of `number` or by the combined values of `city`, `zip-code` and `address`?

Comment: First I want to group it by 'number' and then by by combined value of 'city', 'zip-code' and 'address'. Just edited my question again to explain that.

Comment: That is not what your expected result looks like: you do NOT have a group by `number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, your stylesheet will produce an error because the expression you used in:

```
<xsl:key name="details-key" match="details" use="city,'_',zip-code,'_',address" />
```

is not a valid expression in XPath 1.0.

If you want to group the `details`  elements by the combined values of `city`, `zip-code` and `address`, you should define your key as:

```
<xsl:key name="details-key" match="details" use="concat(city, '_', zip-code, '_', address)" />
```

Now, if I go by your expected output instead of by your description, you actually want to create a group for each unique combination of `number` and address. So something along the lines of:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="k1" match="next" use="concat(number, '_', details/city,'_', details/zip-code,'_', details/address)" />
    
<xsl:template match="db">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="next[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', concat(number, '_', details/city,'_', details/zip-code,'_', details/address))[1])]">
            <next>
                <xsl:copy-of select="name | surname | number"/>
                <details>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="city | zip-code | address"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="group-details" select="key('k1', concat(number, '_', details/city,'_', details/zip-code,'_', details/address))/details" />
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$group-details/phone[text()] | $group-details/fax[text()]"/>
                </details>
            </next>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is  exactly what I expected. Thank you very much!